# Query PFObject based on ACL in CloudCode

Tags: parse-platform

I'd like to create a scheduled job which iterates through all objects of a PFObject class that are "owned" by a specific user, which is dynamic. Ownership is defined by the default ACL in the app, which is set to allow read/write access only to the current user, so every row of this PFObject will only be accessible to that particular user.

I know I'll need to use the master key in this CloudCode function so I can access objects that are normally not readable. How can I construct a PFQuery to return objects that are visible by a particular user? I can create the ACL in CloudCode, can I set this ACL on a PFQuery?

Comment: I have a similar problem that I'm looking for a solution. Since last time you asked, have you found any lead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You'll need to add the owner's user pointer to a new column on the database and maintain that column to query by it. You can do this in a before save hook, if the owner column is empty then add a pointer to the user. I think you can get the user ID from the ACL you can use to set this, you just can't query by it. If not you'll have to figure out another way to set this, the calling user or something else.